# MongoDB ObjectID() -> Can you create a 'simplified' one?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to find a way to create a document key [not `primary key`, but still unique] that is user friendly (like 6 digits/letters long or something).  I've looked at using a `SequenceField` [`mongoengine`], but I've also read about its drawbacks and the preference for `ObjectIDs` instead.

Basically, I'm trying to achieve something like [this MongoDB blogpost](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-document-versioning-pattern), where I can auto_version documents, but ideally also have a user friendly key-field that allows me to pull up all versions of the document at once.

I hope that makes sense... I'm new to MongoDB.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can self generate a uuid to be used as a unique identifier (e.g. doc_id) for versioning, and keep ObjectID as a _id.

Example packages

Nodejs - https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Golang - https://github.com/google/uuid

Python - https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Comment: Nice, thanks! Dont suppose you know a python one off hand?    And how do you make sure that its unique in the database?

Comment: The chance of uuid collision is very very very very low (1 in 2.71 quintillion). You can read the link I provided for python. It's only unique for the document, if you do versioning then each version should have the same uuid, though they may have different _id (ObjectID)

Comment: Of course there are also instances of collision - You can refer to this github post https://github.com/ramsey/uuid/issues/80